# Add SSH Key to Heroku (Noob Question following railstutorial.org)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, cygwin, heroku

Beeing new to programming I'm trying to learn RoR using railstutorial.org and ran into a problem in chapter 1.4.1 (http://railstutorial.org/book#sec:1.4.1). Whentrying to add my SSH key the following happend:

```
    Basti@Basti-PC ~
$ heroku keys:add
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load --
readline (LoadError)
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-1.10.14/lib/heroku/comma
nds/app.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-1.10.14/lib/heroku/comma
nd.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-1.10.14/lib/heroku/comma
nd.rb:5:in `each'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-1.10.14/lib/heroku/comma
nd.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-1.10.14/bin/heroku:7:in
`<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'
```

I'm running Windows Vista using Cygwin. I have installed ruby-1.9.2-p0 and Rails 3.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

The Ruby you are using wasn't compiled against the 'readline' library. Compiling ruby with `readline` support on Windows involves getting a copy of Visual Studio and compiling a lot of stuff with your bare hands.

Normally I'd recommend you use rvm, but rvm doesn't support windows for exactly the reason I just mentioned.

My recommendation would be to develop on a Linux machine or a Mac. Having a Unix environment about is a **must** for any serious developer.

If you're really attached to your Windows, here's a guide on installing Ruby 1.9 on Windows, including `readline`, but I don't know if it'll solve the issue you're currently having.

Answer (score 0):

Use RailsInstaller.org. See my post http://rails.webintellix.com/2011/01/19/rails-installer-on-windows/.